# How NodeJS (Backend) listen permanently to events in Opensea?

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, opensea

I have created a smart contract using solidity with ERC-1155 token standard and published my NFTs on opensea. But how can my nodejs (backend, not frontend) listen to the NFT success transfer event performed at opensea in order to store some value in my database?

Comment: you may listen to smart contract events with ethersjs in your backend using default provider(it may be slow due to high traffic on it) or using any other RPC providers using your own account keys in backend.

Comment: Thanks @ajay, may i know how can i only filter the latest event using ethers.js? Currently it return all previous events.